# androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.6.0 and NavigationRuntimeIssueRegistry has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: android-jetpack, android-navigation

`implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3"` was updated to `implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.6.0"`.

Now, Android Studio throws the following warning when building the app:

```
Could not load custom lint check jar file C:\Users\h1234\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\cc1b5b923bf2c06daef854f9ccc3f497\transformed\navigation-runtime-2.6.0\jars\lint.jar
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: androidx/navigation/runtime/lint/NavigationRuntimeIssueRegistry has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.consumeClassData(UrlClassLoader.java:257)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.JdkZipResourceFile.findClass(JdkZipResourceFile.java:89)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.JarLoader.findClass(JarLoader.java:63)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClassInLoader(ClassPath.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClassWithoutCache(ClassPath.java:235)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClass(ClassPath.java:202)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:209)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry$Factory.loadIssueRegistry(JarFileIssueRegistry.kt:257)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry$Factory.get(JarFileIssueRegistry.kt:183)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry$Factory.get(JarFileIssueRegistry.kt:144)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JarFileIssueRegistry$Factory.get$default(JarFileIssueRegistry.kt:119)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.registerCustomDetectors(LintDriver.kt:725)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.initializeExtraRegistries(LintDriver.kt:610)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.doAnalyze(LintDriver.kt:503)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyzeOnly(LintDriver.kt:448)
    at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient$analyzeOnly$1.invoke(LintCliClient.kt:247)
    at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient$analyzeOnly$1.invoke(LintCliClient.kt:247)
    at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.kt:289)
    at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run$default(LintCliClient.kt:272)
    at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.analyzeOnly(LintCliClient.kt:247)
    at com.android.tools.lint.Main.run(Main.java:1668)
    at com.android.tools.lint.Main.run(Main.java:274)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction.invokeLintMainRunMethod(AndroidLintWorkAction.kt:96)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction.runLint(AndroidLintWorkAction.kt:85)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction.execute(AndroidLintWorkAction.kt:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The app uses the recommended Gradle JDK:
[image]

I can download a higher JDK (e.g., 17, 18) but as far as I know, they are experimental. I thought I saw a warning somewhere in Android Studio about their experimental nature but I cannot recall precisely where I saw it when I tried a higher version. Is androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.6.0 experimental? What is the proper way to handle this? The highest priority for this app which has millions of downloads is its reliability.